# Resizing and cropping images using ImageResizer

Tags: c#, imageresizer, resize-crop

I'm trying to resize and then square-crop incoming images. I have my image in a `ReadOnlyStream` and would like to output to `MemoryStream`.

I'm using [ImageResizer](https://github.com/imazen/resizer) library to do this.

I'd like my images to first reduce in size and then center-square-crop them. I'm using this code, but it doesn't produce what I require. It produces nothing...

```
var resultStream = new MemoryStream();
ImageJob job = new ImageJob(imageStream, resultStream, new Instructions {
    Width = 100,
    Height = 100,
    Mode = FitMode.Crop
});
job.Build();
```

This code should downsample large images and crop them based on library defaults (center cropping).

I didn't provide any specific configuration in web.config because as I understand things it's not required.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: When you say it produces nothing, do you mean that resultStream.Length == 0? You'll naturally need to re-seek the memory stream to 0 after ImageResizer has written to it.

Comment: @ComputerLinguist: I assumed that readers of the stream initially set position to start to prevent something like this to happen. Let me try it right away and see what happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ImageResizer does not reset the output stream position to 0 after writing to it, as this would break non-seekable write streams like HttpResponseStream.

You need to call `resultStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);` before reading from it.